# Add SSH key to sourcetree for amazon webservices repo

Tags: ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

SO im following the directions on sourcetree that tells me how to add an ssh key for my git repo but when i go to add an account the only options are bitbucket, bitbucket server and github. Since theres no option for Amazon Code Commit repo can i assume sourcetree is not set up to push to an amazon webservices git repo?

I already have the ssh key setup and can push to my repo using terminal im just wondering why amazon is not an option